# Returning String value from Android Activity to JS function

Tags: javascript, android, string

i am trying to return a string value to JS function from android activity.
the JS function first calls the android activity method and that method then return a string value but its not working ... take a look on code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function PicMethod(){

    var path = activity.getPic();
  alert(path); 
    }

    </script>
```

Here is the android activity method

```
 public String getPic()
    {
 String temp="abcd";
return temp;
    }
```

Comment: how you are adding to js interface?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I notice there is a typo in your javascript code:  alret (path) should be alert(path);

Comment: sorry that was a typing mistake i didn't copied it from code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, there are different ways of accomplishing this. The difficulty lies in that you want to do things in the onload method.

If it is possible to pass in the string after the page is loaded, you could use

```
String jsString = "javascript:addData('" + theString + "');");
webView.loadUrl(jsString);
```

if you really need the data accessible on the onload method of the page, you could modify the url called to to include query data if possible. Something like:

```
String urlWithData = yourUrl + "?data=" + theString;
webView.loadUrl(urlWithData);
```

and then use standard javascript to parse window.location.search to get the data.

Finally, if you can't modify the URL for some reason, you can use a callback object to let the javascript get the value:

```
private class StringGetter {
   public String getString() {
       return "some string";
   }
}
```

and then when config your webView with this callback before loading the url:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new StringGetter(), "stringGetter");
```

and in the onload method of the page you could use:

```
var theString = stringGetter.getString();
```

Hope this helps!

Regards:@albin

Comment: actually the thing is that i am calling PicMethod() on html button click and this method calls getPic() in get pic i open android camera activity and save the path of picture user just took and return it to JS function ...

Comment: what is the type of your image ?

Comment: path of picture you are saving right ?? so you can send that as a string. you try that?

Comment: no error in LogCat and no alert showing in response . .

Comment: are you sure about the server. Do you test that in some browser ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50124/discussion-between-sreekanthss-and-adil-waqar)